# request / post username/login not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, authentication, request

I am trying to log in with this code:

```
with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'https://ww2.eagle.org/en.html'
    c.get(url)
    login_data = {
        'username': 'username',
        'password': 'pw',
    }
    c.post(url,data=login_data,headers={"Referer":"https://ww2.eagle.org/en.html"})
```

In the website with the code below:

```
<div id="signinFormId" class="section-label">
    <form name="signinForm" method="post" action="https://www.eagle.org/security/GatewayLogin" target="_blank" class="signin-form">
        <span id="close-login" class="close-login">×</span>
        <div class="title-login-window">Login</div>
        <fieldset>
          <input type="text" name="username" id="username-login" required="" class="input-login">
          <label class="input-lbl-login user" for="username-login">Username</label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password-login" required="" class="input-login">
          <label class="input-lbl-login pass" for="password-login">Password</label>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="links-container">
            <input type="submit" class="btn-login" value="Login">
            <span class="links-login-wrapper">
                <a href="/en/abs-eagle-technical-support.html" class="link-login">Help</a>
                <a href="/en/my-eagle-user-id-request.html" class="link-login">Register</a>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div id="loginMsg">
            <p class="error-msg-login">Login failed. Please enter a valid username and password.</p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I get no error, but the login does not go through.
I used similar code to other pages and it worked before.
I think maybe it has to do with a button that need to be pressed for the login page to appear, but I am not sure... 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to submit data to URL specified in `action` attr of `form`, [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-action):

```
c.post('https://www.eagle.org/security/GatewayLogin', ...
```

ps: you really shouldn't post out your username and password.